# Calling a Function Twice And Saving A Different Value Each Time

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am very new to C and am having some issues with a function I am writing. The assignment is to write a function in which it prompts for height and width parameters to draw a box with. I have the function written and it compiles correctly, but the issue I'm having is that I need to call the function twice and save a width from the first call, and a height from the second. Now, this would be easy if I could use pass-by-reference, but I am not allowed to as the function has to be an int. Here is what I have so far.

```
//LaxScorupi
//11/21/2021
// C

 #include <cstdio>

int GetSize(int min, int max)
{
int range;

while (range < min || range > max)
{
    printf("Please enter a value between %d and %d: ", min, max);
    scanf("%d", &range);
}

return range;
}

/*
This is where I think I am missing something obvious. Currently, I 
have printf in place to 
just read the value back to me, but I know my "range" will be saved as 
whatever my second call
of GetSize is. I've tried creating variables for height and width, but 
am unsure how to take 
my return defined as range and store it as two different values. 
*/
 int main ()
{
int min;
int max;
int range;

range = GetSize(2, 80);
printf("Your width is %d\n", range;

range = GetSize(2, 21);
printf("Your height is %d\n", range);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance- Lax Scorupi

Comment: What is the problem? Are you unable to save in a variable the result of the function call?

Comment: My issue is that when I call the function, I return only one value, which is defined as range. I would like to call the function twice and assign both the output for each time as a variable height and width. The simplest way is to use pass-by-reference, but I am not allowed to for this assignment.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the question. If you found a solution write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: pass by reference will not help you here

Answer (score 0):

```
struct
{
   int height;
   int width;
}range;

range.width = GetSize(2, 80);
range.height = GetSize(2, 21);

print("Height:%d, Width:%d\n", range.height, range.width);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can just save them in two different variables and store them in an array so u can use them later.I just added the names and the array into your code down here.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int GetSize(int min, int max)
{
int range;

while (range < min || range > max)
{
printf("Please enter a value between %d and %d: ", min, max);
scanf("%d", &range);
}

return range;
}

int main ()
{
int min;
int max;
int range1, range2;

range1 = GetSize(2, 80);

printf("Your width is %d\n", range1);

range2 = GetSize(2, 21);
printf("Your height is %d\n", range2);

int a[2] = {range1, range2};
printf("%d %d", a[0], a[1]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly